# Identify specific curl multi response

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I use `curl_multi_exec()` to request several websites in parallel. Say, `URL1`, `URL2`, and `URL3`. As soon as one of these websites returns a result, I can process it and then wait for the next response.

Now I need to know, based on the response of the request, which URL this result comes from. I cannot simply check the URL from the response as there might be redirections. So what is the best way to identify from which URL (`URL1`, `URL2`, or `URL3`) the response came from? Can the information from `curl_multi_info_read()` or `curl_getinfo()` somehow be used for that? Is there a cURL Option that I can set and request for that?

I also tried storing the cURL handlers before requesting the URLs and compare them with `curl_multi_info_read($curlMultiHandle)['handle']` but as this is a resource, it is not really comparable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to attach custom data to handle

```
curl_setopt($handle, \CURLOPT_PRIVATE, json_encode(['id' => $query_id]));
```

and then fetch this data

```
curl_getinfo($handle, \CURLINFO_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have multiple Image objects for which you need to load the data. You run your requests in parallel and don't know the order of download completion. So you have to identify somehow your concrete Image object when you receive the data. Instead of using urls (which might change after redirection) as keys in an associative array of Image objects I recommend the following simple approach.

```
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    $activeHandles = array();
    $loadingImages = array();

    function loadImage(Image $image) {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image->getUrl());
      curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
      ...
      $this->loadingImages[] = $image;
      $activeHandles[] = $ch;
    }

    function retrieveImages() {
      // Somewhere you run curl_multi_exec($mh, $running).
      // Here you get the results.
      while ($result = curl_multi_info_read($mh)) {
        // How to get the data is out of our scope.
        // We are interested in identifying the image object.
        $ch = $result['handle'];
        $idx = array_search($ch, $activeHandles);
        $image = $loadingImages[$idx];
        if ($success) {
          // Don't remember to free resources!
          unset($activeHandles[$idx]);
          unset($loadingImages[$idx]);
          curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
          ........
        }
      }
    }
```